# Merge data-frames by row with unequal dimensions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have the following data-frames:

```
a<-data.frame(A=3,B=9,C=10,D=6)
print(a)
  A B  C D
1 3 9 10 6
b<-data.frame(A=1,B=2,D=5)
print(b)
  A B D
1 1 2 5
```

I am trying to bind these together by row so that the corresponding column names line up, and NAs are yielded where corresponding values are missing so that the final result is:

```
  print(c)
  A B C  D
1 3 9 6  10
2 1 2 NA 5
```

I have tried the following:

```
rbind(a,b)
merge(a,b,byrow=TRUE)
```

But neither work, any suggestions?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table`.  We keep the data.frames in a `list` and use `rbindlist` with the option `fill=TRUE` to generate NA for missing columns in a dataset.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(a,b), fill=TRUE)
#   A B  C D
#1: 3 9 10 6
#2: 1 2 NA 5
```

---

Another option is `bind_rows` from `dplyr` which is an efficient implementation of `do.call(rbind, ...)` for row binding many dataframes together.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a,b)
#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

#    A     B     C     D
#  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     3     9    10     6
#2     1     2    NA     5
```

Comment: @costebk08 Thanks for the feedback.  Glad to know that it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could use joins, as implemented in `dplyr`.

```
full_join(a,b)

   Joining by: c("A", "B", "D")
     A B  C D
   1 3 9 10 6
   2 1 2 NA 5
```